Simple-ish grad question: grad of field of arbitrary dimensions
I'm doing problem set #0 from Stanford's CS229 course. They asked a pretty simple question:
what is $\nabla f(x)$ where $f(x)=\frac{1}{2}x^TAx+b^Tx$, $A$ is symmetric, and $b$ and $x$ are vectors?
I realised I've done loads of this stuff in 2 and 3 dimensions, but never in an arbitrary number of dimensions. The answers made is seem like $Ax+b$ was an obvious answer. Is it a common identity that $\nabla (x^TAx)=2Ax$? (for symmetric A)
And could anyone please recommend a good resource for learning to do maths with vectors with arbitrary dimensions?

A nice book is Calculus on manifolds by Spivak (don't worry if you don't know manifolds they only come up at the very end). Now "differentiating" a multivariable function defined in terms of matrix multiplication is a classic concept but saying if it's common or not depends on your definition of common.
